# Get user friendly MSSQL server's product name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a way to get the user friendly MSSQL product name.

I've tried:

```
select @@version
```

but it returns to much information (I don't want to parse it now)

`Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64)   Apr 22 2011 19:23:43   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: )`

Another try was

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

which returns `10.50.1617.0 RTM Developer Edition (64-bit)`

I tried to get the `SERVERPROPERTY` for every property from this [list](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx), but couldn't find the needed one.

Is there a way to get the string **Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2** only?

Thanks

Comment: So why can't you parse the `@@version` string? Just trim it up to the first hyphen looks like it will do it.

Comment: @gvee I can parse it, but I want to avoid it as we can't know if microsoft will change the string format or not. I don't even know if the @@version output format is the same for all already released MSSql versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT LEFT(@@version, CHARINDEX(' - ', @@version)) ProductName;
```

*Note: you can obviously adjust it to your needs (like trim RTM if you have to etc.)*

Sample output SQL Server 2008:

```
|                         PRODUCTNAME |
|-------------------------------------|
| Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)  |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21242)** demo

Sample output SQL Server 2012:

```
|                PRODUCTNAME |
|----------------------------|
| Microsoft SQL Server 2012  |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/7467)** demo

Comment: thanks, but I would like to avoid parsing as we can't know if microsoft will change the string format or not. I don't even know if the @@version output format is the same for all already released MSSql versions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (if you need to remove `(RTM)`):

```
 select 
     case when charindex('-', @@version,0) < charindex('(', @@version,0)
          then left(@@version, charindex('-', @@version,0)-1)
     else left(@@version, charindex('(', @@version,0)-1) end as myserver

 --Results 
 Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
 Microsoft SQL Server 2012
```

Else

```
 select left(@@version, charindex('-', @@version,0)-1) as myserver

 --Results 
 Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)
 Microsoft SQL Server 2012
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8)**

Comment: thanks, but I would like to avoid parsing as we can't know if microsoft will change the string format or not. I don't even know if the @@version output format is the same for all already released MSSql versions.

Comment: Both work well for 2008 and above. I don't have lower versions to test but sure it should be okay.

Comment: I'm worried more about future MSSQL products, can't be sure that it will remain the same that's why I looked for an elegant way to retrieve the property, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so how about this then... It's not a wholly complete answer but I'm putting it out there as something for people to toy with.

Obviously not an exhaustive list so isn't future proof but gives you something to work with. I've included the many references I've used within the code itself:

```
SELECT 'Microsoft SQL Server '
     + CASE ParseName(Cast(ServerProperty('ProductVersion') As varchar(100)), 4)
         /* This function did not exist in versions prior to 2005
         WHEN  6 THEN '6' -- there is a v6.5 but we'll let that return "6 R2"
         WHEN  7 THEN '7.0'
         WHEN  8 THEN '2000'
         */
         -- How to determine the version and edition of SQL Server: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185
         WHEN  3 THEN 'Mobile/Compact Edition'
         WHEN  9 THEN '2005'
         WHEN 10 THEN '2008'
         WHEN 11 THEN '2012'
         WHEN 12 THEN '2014' -- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/199f43df-243e-4473-a765-e0e45c0ca3d5/sql-server-2014-release-date-and-version-number
         ELSE '(unknown)'
       END
     + CASE ParseName(Cast(ServerProperty('ProductVersion') As varchar(100)), 3)
         WHEN 50 THEN ' R2'    -- 
         WHEN 25 THEN ' Azure' -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff951630.aspx
         WHEN  5 THEN ' 3.5'   -- CE https://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2008/02/08/sql-server-compact-release-versions.aspx
         ELSE ''
       END As sql_version
```

Comment: thanks, but future modifications is something that I'm trying to avoid. For existing (and probably for future) versions the parsing solution is fine